# Python Recursive Family Tree

Tags: python, recursion

How do I recursively return a whole family tree, sequentially by each generations using a function?

E.g. `('Alan', [('Bob', [('Chris', []), ('Debbie', [('Cindy', [])])]), ('Eric', [('Dan', []), ('Fanny', [('George', [])])]), ('Hannah', [])])`

Expected Return:
`['Alan', 'Bob', 'Eric', 'Hannah', 'Chris', 'Debbie', 'Dan', 'Fanny', 'Cindy', 'George']`

What I have now:

```
def get_family_members(head):
    family_tree = []
    def child(head):
        family_tree.append(head[0])

        for kids in head:
            if isinstance(kids,list):
                for kids_kids in kids:
                    family_tree.append(kids_kids[0])
                for kids_kids in kids:
                    kids_kids = kids_kids[1]
                    for kids_kids_kids in kids_kids:
                        child(kids_kids_kids)
    child(head)

    return family_tree
```

Comment: I ran it and I got `['Alan', 'Bob', 'Eric', 'Hannah', 'Chris', 'Debbie', 'Cindy', 'Dan', 'Fanny', 'George']` as an output? Does order matters here?

Comment: @Pratik Gandhi It is family tree so i assume that order matters here.

Comment: @PratikGandhi Yes order does matter as it must be <grandparents>, <all parents> , <all children>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to achieve my solution **without** any libraries.

**SOLUTION:**

```
def get_family_members(head):
    # head - ('Mary', [list of children tuples])
    # return a list of everyone
    # modify the code below

    result = [head[0]]
    children_list = head[1] # list of tuples

    not_done = True
    while not_done:
        next_list = []

        # loop through each tuple
        # add parent to result, add the children tuples to next_list
        for tup in children_list:
            head = tup[0]
            list_of_children = tup[1]

            result.append(head)

            # += here because you want to add the tuples not a list of tuples
            next_list += list_of_children

        # replace the children_list with the next_list to loop through in the next while loop iteration
        children_list = next_list

        # end while loop if no more children to look for 
        if children_list == []:
            not_done = False

    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Your expected output is based on a breadth-first search rather than a depth-first search, so you should use a queue rather than recursion:

```
from collections import deque

def get_family_members(head):
    family = []
    queue = deque([head])
    while queue:
        name, children = queue.popleft()
        family.append(name)
        queue.extend(children)
    return family
```

so that:

```
head = ('Alan', [('Bob', [('Chris', []), ('Debbie', [('Cindy', [])])]), ('Eric', [('Dan', []), ('Fanny', [('George', [])])]), ('Hannah', [])])
print(get_family_members(head))
```

outputs:

```
['Alan', 'Bob', 'Eric', 'Hannah', 'Chris', 'Debbie', 'Dan', 'Fanny', 'Cindy', 'George']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
def get_names(d, c = 0):
   for a, b in d:
      yield (c, a)
      yield from [] if not b else get_names(b, c+1)

result = [b for _,b in sorted(get_names([d]), key=lambda x:x[0])]
```

Output:

```
['Alan', 'Bob', 'Eric', 'Hannah', 'Chris', 'Debbie', 'Dan', 'Fanny', 'Cindy', 'George']
```